# Can I add the same DataRow to a DataTable multiple times?

Tags: ado.net, recursion, datatable, dataset

If I have a DataTable and want to create a new row I first call `DataTable.NewRow()` which returns a DataRow. This row then has the schema of the Table, and I can set the value of each field in the row. At this point does the Table "know" about the Row, or does that only happen after I call `DataTable.Rows.Add(DataRow row)`?

If I call `DataTable.Rows.Add()` more then once are duplicate rows created in the data table with duplicate values?

The reason I ask is I'm trying to write a recursive function that will iterate down a tree structure and populate a DataTable with values. So I have situations where rows being created for each child will have columns that have all the same values because they come from the parent.

So my idea was to pass a DataRow with the parent's information to each child. The child would add its information and then add the row to the table. But I'm trying to figure out if I need to call `DataTable.NewRow()` for each child, or if new rows will be created automatically if I add the same row multiple times.

Comment: Wow - asked 10 hours ago, and already showed up in google when I went looking for a similar thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, but it's easy to copy a row so you can get what you want (assumes the existing row is in a variable called existingRow):

```
var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
newRow.ItemArray = existingRow.ItemArray;
dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, old question. But Michael's answer does work. I needed to add multiple duplicate rows to a `DataTable` for a scheduling app. With `dt.Rows.Add(_Users)` I got the error:

> This row already belongs to this table

But using this, I could loop through and hold as many positions open for a job as needed Where "Length" is the number of positions to hold open for a job:

```
int Length = int.Parse(TextBox6.Text.Trim());
for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
{
  Users.Rows.Add("9999", "Open");
}
```

Searching Google for this sucks, because most people want to remove duplicate rows in a `DataTable`, and not add duplicate rows in a `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will generate an exception of type System.ArgumentException.

Comment: Is there an easy way of creating a Duplicate DataRow with the same values?

Answer (score -1):

i recommend that you put the data in a array and then add the data to data table
e.g.

```
yourDataTable.Rows.Add(data[0]........);
```

`newdatarow` will generate exception error